# How to create internet tunnel to my port http 80 like NGROK to show my website to my clients

Tags: 18.04, server

I run on VirtualBox the Ubuntu Server 18.04, I had installed LAMP, now I want to have access to my web server from internet to show websites to my clients. Help me, please. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ssh remote forwarding feature
In OpenSSH, [remote SSH port forwarding](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example) is specified using the `-R` option
You can find free ssh servers providers online : https://www.fastssh.com/, https://www.sshkit.com/, https://www.vpnjantit.com/, https://spotssh.com/

```
# on the VM lamp server

ssh -nN -R 80:vmhost:80 public.external.com

-R for remote forwarding
-n prevents reading from stdin
-N do not execute remote commands

# this will make the external server forward tpc/80 traffic to vmhost:80 via an ssh tunnel
```